# Cannot see the gui for the SingleLaneBridge java applet example

Tags: eclipse, command-line, netbeans6.8, applet

I went to the this java **[site](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~jnm/book/book_applets/SingleLaneBridge.html)** and loaded the files in a new project in netbeans 6.8 .
I removed the package declaration and put them in the default package of the project.
I tried to compile it by right clicking and selecting run(Shift + F6) on the **SingleLaneBridge.java** file. This program compiled without errors.

This is what I got :

[image]

Then I tried another method, which included copying the java files to a folder and compiled them manually using commandLine. Then made an html file and put the reference to the SingleLaneBridge.class file. Still I got a similar grey screen with the buttons. Then I tried again by downloading the pictures and the sound file (Note: All this time images and the sound file were called from the website):

1)
[Red car](https://wwwhomes.doc.ic.ac.uk/~jnm/book/book_applets/image/redcar.gif)

2)
[Blue car](https://wwwhomes.doc.ic.ac.uk/~jnm/book/book_applets/image/bluecar.gif)

3)
[Bridge](https://wwwhomes.doc.ic.ac.uk/~jnm/book/book_applets/image/bridge.gif)

4)
[Crash sound file](https://wwwhomes.doc.ic.ac.uk/~jnm/book/book_applets/sound/crash.au)

Then I put the images in the folder where the notepad files were. The image and sound path(s) was set appropriately in the **BridgeCanvas.java** file so dont worry about that.

After this I tried it out in Eclipse as well. But the same gray applet window with buttons showed up.

I would like to see the **cars and bridge** in the applet, like in this **[site](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~jnm/book/book_applets/SingleLaneBridge.html)**.

Thanks for your time.

Tlna